# Access data from html form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a form in an application that goes like this :

```
    <form action="" style="max-width:500px;margin:auto"> 
            
              <div class="input-container_sensor_form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                    <input class="input_field_sensor_form" type="text" placeholder="Sensor name" name="sensor_name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                    <span class="text-center">
                        <select name="sensor_form_sensor_category" class="sensor_form_sensor_category" id="sensor_form_sensor_category" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="sensor_form_sensor_category">
                        <option></option>
                        <option name="tree_sensor" >Tree Sensor</option>
                        <option name="weather_sensor" >Weather Station</option>
                        </select>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                    <input class="input_field_sensor_form" type="text" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude" name="latitude">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                    <input class="input_field_sensor_form" type="text" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude" name="longitude">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                
              <br>
              <div id="map_sensor_form"></div>
              <br>
              <input type="hidden" id="field_id" name="field_id" value="">
              <button type="submit" class="btn_sensor_form">Register</button>
        </form>
```

with the following form :

```
class AddSensor(forms.Form):
   
    sensor_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200 )
    choice = forms.ChoiceField()
    longitude = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16)
    latitude = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16)
```

How do i match the inputs with the form ? I've seen in the django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-form-class) that its referencing it through label but I do not have any. I want to keep the form as it is .

Comment: Basically you would like to save the form data into database successfully, with html form rather than django's form?

Comment: I'd like to pass the form's input to my AddSensor form and save it to a model instance in my database yes. Im not using `forms.ModelForm` as there are some differences to my model and those are the only values i want to save

Comment: You can make view and get form's data using `request.GET.get('any_name')` and save it in the model. One more thing remove the empty action attribute, then also it will take current page route.

Comment: Is there a way to connect my AddSensor fields with the html form's  though as to make the validation with `.is_valid()` easier? Django docs use `forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)` is there something similar for my case?

Comment: That's what i was thinking, you can only use `is_valid()`, if you render django's form but in your case, you cannot use that, but you can use html functionality in forms for restrictions. Do you want me to write an answer, that how can you save data to model using html's form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make use of `form.cleaned_data`
create a model instance and assign values from `form.cleaned_data`

to `form.is_valid()` work, you can make sure that the html field id is same as that of `AddSensor` form field.
for instance: `AddSensor` form field `sensor_name` and html field with id `sensor_name`

```py
# views.py
   
from .models import YourModel # import model
from .forms import AddSensor # import form

def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddSensor(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            obj = YourModel()
            obj.sensor_name = form_data.get("sensor_name")
            # other fields
            obj.save()
            # return or redirect
    else:
        form = AddSensor()

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form})
```

here, instead of rendering the form using django forms, the form is hardcoded with the same id's that a django form would render. By matching the id's in the hardcoded html and django form, `form.is_valid()` can be called. thus `form.cleaned_data` can be accessed with the form field names

Comment: Well, it is through django's form.

Comment: instead of rendering the form using django forms, the form is hardcoded with the same id's that a django form would render. By matching the id's in the hardcoded html and django form, `form.is_valid()` can be called. thus `form.cleaned_data` can be accessed with the form field names